# VB.net Forecolor in every listview item

Tags: vb.net, listview

guys can you help me figure out how to put some forecolor in every listview item?

what I am trying to do is: I want to populate the listview with some forecolors in the items just like this

Example:

```
> ColumnHeader1            ColumnHeader2     ColumnHeader3
> Executive(W/Forecolor)    texttexttext     texttexttexttext
> Employee(Plain w/out FC)  texttexttext     texttexttexttext
```

here is my code:

```
Private Sub loadRemarks()
    Try
        jonsqlcon.Close()
        jonsqlcon.ConnectionString = dllConstring
        jonsqlcon.Open()

        Dim selStaff As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM StaffMember WHERE Staff_IDNo ='" & Notification.lblStaffID.Text & "'", jonsqlcon)
        Dim setStaff As New DataSet
        Dim accLvl As String
        selStaff.Fill(setStaff)
        accLvl = setStaff.Tables(0).DefaultView.Item(0).Item("AccessLVL").ToString

        If accLvl = "2" Then
            ListView1.ForeColor = Color.Aqua
        End If

        Dim loadChat As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM RemarksConvo WHERE Application_ID = '" & ClientAccountStatusViewer.txtClientID.Text & "' AND Room ='" & lvlStorage.Text & "'", jonsqlcon)
        reader = loadChat.ExecuteReader

        ListView1.Items.Clear()
        Do While reader.Read = True
            list = ListView1.Items.Add(reader(3).ToString)
            list.SubItems.Add(reader(4).ToString)
            list.SubItems.Add(reader(5).ToString)
            list.SubItems.Add(reader(6).ToString)
        Loop
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this a WinForms ListView?

Comment: yes sir it is a WindowsForm Listview

Comment: Can you explain some details of your code? What is the relationship between the table StaffMember and RemarksConvo? How do you establish that a record in RemarksConvo is relative to an Executive and an Employee?

Comment: I did this some months ago with the BackColor of a ComboBox. I did it by handling the ComboBox.DrawItem event and defining a structure ColoredComboBoxItem. Maybe this link will help you: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?719335-RESOLVED-ComboBox-with-different-color-Items-and-DropDownList-Style

Comment: is the StaffMember I am fetching and getting the accesslevel of the user while the RemarksConvo it is the query that populates the listview

Comment: OK, but if you want to color each item differently then you need to have in the RemarksConvo something that tells you if the comment has been done by an Executive or by an Employee otherwise you just set the ForeColor for every item. What are exactly the fields of RemarksConvo (all of them not just the 4 that you put in the ListView)

Comment: ConvoID(PK),Application_ID,StaffIDNo,StaffUsername,Desicion,Remarks,Date,Room

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you should worry is about the Sql Injection problem of your code. Do not use string concatenation to build a query text but always a parameterized text. Not only your command is more clear but there is no way that an hacker could tamper your text to wreak havoc with your database.

Second. You can bring the information about the level of your remark's author by executing a join between the two tables. The field Staff_IDNo in both tables links the records from the remarks to the table with the info about the level of the remark's author

Finally, a ListViewItem (the object returned by ListView.Items.Add) supports the ForeColor property and you can simply set the color row by row while you add items to your listview

```
 Dim loadChat As New SqlCommand("SELECT r.*, s.AccessLVL FROM RemarksConvo r
                                 JOIN StaffMember s ON s.Staff_IDNo = r.Staff_IDNo
                                 WHERE r.Application_ID = @appId
                                       AND r.Room = @room", jonsqlcon)
 loadChat.Parameters.Add("@appId", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = ClientAccountStatusViewer.txtClientID.Text 
 loadChat.Parameters.Add("@room", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = lvlStorage.Text)
 reader = loadChat.ExecuteReader
 ListView1.Items.Clear()
  Do While reader.Read
      list = ListView1.Items.Add(reader(3).ToString)
      list.ForeColor = If(reader("AccessLvl").ToString = "2", Color.Acqua, SystemColors.WindowText)
      list.SubItems.Add(reader(4).ToString)
      list.SubItems.Add(reader(5).ToString)
      list.SubItems.Add(reader(6).ToString)
 Loop
```